# Add a network folder as a readonly Windows 8 library location

Tags: windows-8, nas, shared-libraries

I have some movies and music on a NAS drive, and want to allow my children to access them from Windows 8.

My plan was to add the relevant NAS folders as new "library locations" for their Music and Videos libraries.

However, I don't want them to accidentally be able to delete files from the NAS drive, and this is something that they might try to do from within Windows Media Player as they could click delete on songs or videos they don't like.

My question is - is this the best way to give them access to the music & videos, and is it safe from accidental deletion? I can't see a way to mark a library location as read-only.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to change the properties of the folders that the library links to.

What happens if you simply select all the files in Windows explorer, go to properties, and set the read only flag?

If you have more users, you should be able to right click on the folders that the library links to and set specific permissions for specific users.