# How do I add a network folder to a Windows 8 library?

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, shared-libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 - creating a local library with network shares/drives](https://superuser.com/questions/41991/windows-7-creating-a-local-library-with-network-shares-drives)

A follow-up to this question: [Add a network folder as a readonly Windows 8 library location](https://superuser.com/questions/499384/add-a-network-folder-as-a-readonly-windows-8-library-location)

When I try and add a network share to the Windows music library (via right-click on the library in explorer, Properties, Add.., select the network folder, click "Include folder"), I get a message that the folder can't be included in the library because it's not indexed.  The help seems to suggest that I can fix this by making the folder available offline, but that would mean copying it all locally, which would eliminate the much of the point of putting this on the network.

Is there another way to allow the network drive to be indexed?  Or to force windows to ignore the indexing requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Win7 Library Tool](http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/win7-library-tool.html), apparently it works with Windows 8 as well. It will allow you to add an un-indexed UNC path to a library (or any un-indexed location.)

I haven't used it myself, but it comes highly recommended by my office's "mediaphile"... and a couple of sites online.